# how to get elements in an element by attrbutes and update it node with purejs?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a html tag like this :

```
<div data-ctrl="master">
    <div data-text="txtName"></div>
</div>
<div data-ctrl="master">
    <div ><span data-text="txtName"></span> Wiratama</div>
</div>
```

and in js code i have :

```
var txtName = 'Yoza';
```

i want to insert html to every element in document with attribute `data-text="txtName"` in element with `data-ctrl="master"` with pure js.

```
function updateData(txtName){
var html = '<b>' + txtName + '</b>';
//update data for every element with attribute data-text txtName here
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++) {
            if (allElements[i].getAttribute("data-text") !== null) {
                if (allElements[i].getAttribute("data-text") === 'txtName') {
                    console.log(nodeTemplate);
                    //                    allElements[i].innerHTML = html;
                }

            }
        }
}
```

that is my js code i tried to.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return a list of nodes which match your selection. Then iterate over each of them, setting the `innerHTML` as you go:

```js
function updateData(txtName){
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ctrl="master"] [data-text="txtName"]');
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        nodes[i].innerHTML = "<b>" + txtName + "</b>";
    }
};

updateData("Yoza");
```

```html
<div data-ctrl="master">
    <div data-text="txtName"></div>
</div>
<div data-ctrl="master">
    <div ><span data-text="txtName"></span> Wiratama</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its simple and really what i need

Answer (score 0):

On all modern browsers, and also IE8, you have `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` on elements (and also on `document`), which accept CSS selectors. `querySelector` returns the first matching element (or `null`); `querySelectorAll` returns a list.

So if you have an element and want to find all of the elements within it that have the attribute `data-text="txtName"`, you can do:

```
var list = theElementYouHave.querySelectorAll('[data-text="txtName"]');
```

So for example:

```js
// Get some element
var element = document.getElementById("foo");

// Find all elements inside it that have `data-text` (at all)
snippet.log("Descendant elements with a data-text attribute: " +
            element.querySelectorAll("[data-text]").length);

// Find the *first* element with `data-text="txtName"` and change its
// text to "Yoza":
var txtNameElement = element.querySelector('[data-text="txtName"]');
if (txtNameElement) {
  txtNameElement.innerHTML = "Yoza";
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div data-ctrl="master">
    <div data-text="txtName"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-ctrl="master">
    <div><span data-text="txtName"></span> Wiratama</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: can i use document directly : document.querySelector('[data-text="txtName"]')

Comment: @yozawiratama: Sure, to look throughout the entire document.

Comment: A bit of caution with IE 8 and querySelector: it only supports a fairly simple subset of selectors. The OP wants a selector like: `'[data-ctrl=master] [data-text=txtName]'`. I'm not sure IE 8 supports that.